# Can the Magic Keyboard's lock button do "Lock Screen" with Watch unlock?

Tags: sleep-wake, unlock, screensaver, screen-lock

I'd like the lock button on the Apple Magic Keyboard to lock the screen, start the screen saver, and leave the display on (if connected to power), in such a way that I can unlock quickly later automatically using my Apple Watch. Is this possible?

It seems not to be, because of a difference in behavior between the Lock Screen command (from the Apple Menu, or from Hot Corners Shortcuts) and the behavior of the lock button. In particular I notice this difference when the laptop is closed and connected to an external monitor.

When I invoke Lock Screen (on macOS Sonoma), my screen saver starts, my display stays active, but I need to re-enter my password to unlock the screen. I can't unlock the screen automatically via my Apple watch.

But when I click the keyboard's lock button, the screen saver starts, the display then turns off entirely, but then I can unlock it via my Apple Watch. So the keyboard's lock button is doing something different from the "Lock Screen" command. It's also different from the Sleep command (which can be selected from the Apple menu).

I don't understand what's going on. Is there a setup so the lock button locks the screen, allows watch unlock, but doesn't turn off the display?